# Framework class for parsing type names?

Tags: .net, reflection

I have strings containing fully qualified type names a la [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsftwz6.aspx).  I'm wondering if there is a Framework class that will help me parse out the various components (e.g. generic type parameters).

Note that I can't simply load the Type with Type.GetType and inspect its properties because the type specified by the string may not be accessible in the context I'm trying to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no class designed specifically to parse type strings.  Building one around a regular expression should not be a particularly difficult task though.

Comment: Thanks, I've built my owner parser.  Hopefully it won't break if they add new components to the type names.